# Checking if entered coordinates are valid

Tags: python

So I wrote a python function which tests the input entered by the user in the format `[column][row]` -> eg. "23" for column 2, row 3. I am able to change the size of the board, but I'm not too sure what the best way to implement a check would be to make sure that the program doesn't crush under these inputs, but instead, just prompts the user to enter the coordinates again:

1. The user inputs a blank space (presses enter).
2. The user enters coordinates outside the range of the row or column index.
3. The user enters a letter or any other character than a number.

This is my python check for the moment:

```
def checkIfMoveIsValid(Board, Move):
  Row = Move % 10
  Column = Move // 10
  MoveIsValid = False
  if Board[Row][Column] == " ":
    MoveIsValid = True
  return MoveIsValid
```

I tried implementing this ->

```
  inp = input()
  if inp and inp.isdigit():
    Coordinates = int(inp)
  else:
    return 0
  return Coordinates
```

But this only checks for no coordinate and anything apart from the correct input. It doesn't however check if the coordinates are in range and therefore, if out of range coordinates are entered, the program crashed and it says: `list index out of range`.

Answer (score -1):

I would use two methods. One to get the input and one to check it:

```
def check_input(Board,input):
    #I assume the Board has dimensions (Board.size) x (Board.size)
    #I also assume you can get the dimensions of the board
    return input in range(11,Board.size**2+1)

def get_input():
    valid = False
    while valid is False:
        position = int(raw_input("Enter a valid board position: "))
        valid = check_input(Board,position)
    return position
```